# Java multiple type data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, types

Is there a data structure in Java which can store different types in it? I mean like storing in an array different types (which actually does not work).

Comment: An `Object[]` can store objects of any type.

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to put unrelated objects in one collection. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

more info in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object array but that creates problems when the time comes to retrieve the objects you have stored. However, if you want to get data out of the array, you can only get it as an Object. The following won't work:

```
int i1 = objects[1]; // Won't work. 
Integer i2 = objects[2]; // Also won't work.
```

You have to get it back as an Object:

```
Object o = objects[0]; // Will work.
```

You can't get back the original form now.

Comment: This is 2021.  Don't use raw types.  Also Java is a case sensitive language ... and there isn't an `Add` method or "function".

Comment: This is a java question. Not dotnet. The api of `ArrayList` is quite the same, but java don't use first upper case method names.

Comment: @StephenC I completely misunderstood the question, I have updated the answer and corrected myself.

Comment: @asbachb I completely misunderstood the question, I have updated the answer and corrected myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic collection that can store elements of any type. To define a generic collection, you use the `<>` operator to specify the type of elements that the collection can store. For example, the following code defines a generic collection that can store elements of any type:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>()
list.add(1);
list.add("Hello, world!");
list.add(new Object());
```